# flyway: db init without maven?

Tags: flyway

IMHO using maven for migrations is fine only for development machines.
On servers you don't usually have maven available (and it might be impossible to have it installed there).

So: How do I init a database without maven?
Do I just call flyway.init()?
What if the db is already init-ed?

Can I execute sql statements to init the db?
My foreign keys and indexes are different/messed up in between different databases instances, so I already made a complete schema script and tested it with data export, schema drop, schema re-create and data restore. I am going to do that on all databases to ensure that they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simply call flyway.init()

You can use flyway.status() to check if the DB has been inited.

This process will become easier with Flyway 1.8, where a new property called initOnMigrate has been introduced. The first time it runs, it will then init an existing non-empty database (PROD) when you run migrate or just migrate on an empty one (DEV).